# Near "WHERE" Syntax Error when POSTing to SQLite with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I wish to update two fields in a SQLite database with the coordinates of a marker placed on an image, using Javascript, Ajax and PHP. Currently, when I POST the data, I receive a 'near "WHERE": syntax error' at the console in Chrome. I have read other Stack Overflow threads with the same/similar errors but have yet to find an answer to my problem.

A breakdown of my code:

When a circular marker (div id #001) is dragged and dropped onto an image (for my purposes, a map), the coordinates are recorded in two divs: #x_results and #y_results. This section of the code is working correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var coordinates = function(element) {
        element = $(element);
        var top = element.position().top;
        var left = element.position().left;
        $('#x_results').text(left);
        $('#y_results').text(top);
    }

    $( function () {
        $("#001").draggable({
            start: function() {
                coordinates('#001');
            },
            stop: function() {
                coordinates('#001');
            }
        });         
    } );

</script>
```

I then POST the coordinates to a PHP script by clicking a button (#submit_node), using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submit_node').click(function() {
            var xcoords = $('#x_results').val();
            var ycoords = $('#y_results').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'coords.php',
                data: { x_coords: xcoords, y_coords: ycoords },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

The contents of my PHP script (coords.php) is as follows:

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{   
    function __construct()
    {   
        $this->open('map_test.db');
    }   
}   

$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
        echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}

$x_coords = $_POST["x_coords"];
$y_coords = $_POST["y_coords"];

$sql =<<<EOF
    UPDATE Person SET marker_x = $x_coords WHERE id=1;
    UPDATE Person SET marker_y = $y_coords WHERE id=1;
EOF;

$ret = $db->exec($sql);
if(!$ret){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    echo $db->changes(), "Record updated successfully\n";
}

$db->close();
?>
```

I have been struggling with this for a few days and have reached an impasse. The database file is writable and all necessary files have the correct permissions and ownership (reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver). I can successfully update the 'marker_x' and 'marker_y' values in the database when interacting via the command line:

```
sqlite> UPDATE Person SET marker_x = 31.17 WHERE id = 1;
sqlite> select * from Person;
1|001|Chris|22|Geek|On|lime|31.17|79.558
2|002|John|56|Architect|Error|orange|342.11|y
3|003|Philipa|22|Student|Off|red|342.11|y
4|004|Grant|34|Director|On|lime|342.11|y
```

I would like to store the coordinate values in a SQLite database so that they can later be used to position the marker, thereby achieving persistence.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your code is extremely open to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement for inserting the data from `$_POST`, and you probably want to sanitize the data first.

Comment: Why 2 update statements? `UPDATE Person SET marker_x = $x_coords,  marker_y = $y_coords WHERE id=1` Also parameterize it.

Comment: You need to check what the actual values are for those coordinate parameters. The SQL error is happening because either the X or Y value (or maybe both) are not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I changed the coordinate fields in the database to float and then set '$x_coords = (float) $x_coords;'. I did the same for $y_coords and the database then updated successfully. I also added dataType as 'html' in the ajax POST.

@4castle, Thanks for the suggestion. I will begin reading about sanitizing data and using prepared statements. This is my first coding project so I still have lots to learn. I appreciate your time.